# Exceptions on Client side Aura,LWC

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-web-components, exception

What are types of exceptions on client side in Aura, Lightning Web Components?

Answer (score 1):

JavaScript and Web Platform APIs throw or reject error types like ReferenceError, TypeError and so on. These all inherit from the Error object which has the following properties:

- name – Indicates the type of exception thrown.
- message – Contains the error message.
- stack – Contains the stack trace.

When accessing Salesforce data using Apex or Lightning Data Service, errors are presented using a custom error object with a slightly different structure modeled after the Fetch API’s Response object. Here are a few properties of the custom error object:

- ok – Specifies whether the request was successful or not.
- status – Contains the HTTP status code of the response. For example, 500 for an internal server error.
- statusText – Contains the status message corresponding to the status code.
- body – The response body which varies based on the method that throws the error.

For unhandled exceptions and custom exceptions thrown by Apex, the `body` property holds additional details like the type of exception (`body.exceptionType`), the error message (`body.message`), the Apex stack trace (`body.stackTrace`) , and others. Here’s an example code snippet and the resulting console output.

Instead of repeating the logic to parse different kinds of error objects in each component, you can create a single function that does this and import it as a module in each component.

As a best practice, use the `reduceErrors` function from LWC Recipes (sample app which has a collection of easy-to-digest code examples for Lightning Web Components) to handle different kinds of error objects. This function looks for the message property and concatenates the message if multiple message properties are found. Here’s an example of how it can be used to simplify the previous code snippet.

```js
import { reduceErrors } from 'c/utils';
...

@wire(getRecord, { recordId: '$recordId', fields })
wiredRecord({error, data}) {
    if (error) {
        this.errorMessage = reduceErrors(this.error);
    } else if (data) {
        // Process record data
    }
}
```

`reduceErrors` is defined [here](https://github.com/trailheadapps/lwc-recipes/blob/199cc27d9a20c9b2bf14ed199484908d8a00535b/force-app/main/default/lwc/ldsUtils/ldsUtils.js#L6).

Source: https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/2020/08/error-handling-best-practices-for-lightning-web-components